# Не получается создать "простейший" драйвер в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, c, драйвер

Не получается создать драйвер в Ubuntu (железный бобёр).

Makefile

```
# Makefile – makefile of our first driver

# if KERNELRELEASE is defined, we've been invoked from the
# kernel build system and can use its language.
ifneq (${KERNELRELEASE},)
    obj-m := ofd.o
# Otherwise we were called directly from the command line.
# Invoke the kernel build system.
else
    KERNEL_SOURCE := /lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic/
    PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
    ${MAKE} -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} modules

clean:
    ${MAKE} -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} clean
endif
```

ofd.c
    /* ofd.c - Код нашего первого драйвера */
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
static int __init ofd_init(void) /* Конструктор */
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "dimon ^_^ : ofd registered");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit ofd_exit(void) /* Деструктор*/
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "pumba ;_; : ofd unregistered");
}

module_init(ofd_init);
module_exit(ofd_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("kaban <kaban@bk.ru>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Moi perwii draiwer (Our First Driver)");
```

Получил такой результат [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делал всё по статье [написание простершего драйвера.](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/BOOKS/drivers/linux-device-drivers-02.html) не знаю почему несобралося :Р

---

Поправил и добавил ТАБы.

```
# Makefile – makefile of our first driver

# if KERNELRELEASE is defined, we've been invoked from the
# kernel build system and can use its language.
ifneq (${KERNELRELEASE},)
    obj-m := ofd.o
# Otherwise we were called directly from the command line.
# Invoke the kernel build system.
else
    KERNEL_SOURCE := /lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic/
    PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
    ${MAKE} -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} modules

clean:
    ${MAKE} -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} clean
endif
```

Вот вывод что мне дал компьютер

```
comp@comp0:~$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic/ SUBDIRS=/home/comp modules
make[1]: вход в каталог «/lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic»
make[1]: *** Нет правила для сборки цели «modules».  Останов.
make[1]: выход из каталога «/lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic»
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Странно,даёт ошибку, хотя ядро я указал верное.

```
comp@comp0:~$ uname -r 
4.15.0-47-generic
```

Comment: В Makefile отступы должны делаться одним табом. Если у вас не так (например, вместо табов пробелы) - замените

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[в начале строки с рецептом должен стоять символ табуляции](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipe-Syntax.html).

у вас в файле всего две такие строки (обе начинаются с `${MAKE}`). проконтролируйте, что в их начале стоит именно символ табуляции, а не пробел.

---

в дополнение:

первая из строк, содержащая рецепт, может быть объединена с правилом (см. ссылку выше), через точку с запятой.

т.е. вместо:

```
цель:
    рецепт # здесь в начале строки — символ табуляции
```

можно написать:

```
цель: ; рецепт # здесь только пробелы, которые можно и убрать
```

---

> ```
> make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic/ SUBDIRS=/home/comp modules
> make[1]: вход в каталог «/lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic»
> make[1]: *** Нет правила для сборки цели «modules».  Останов.
> ```

ну, загляните в каталог, где вы пытаетесь выполнить цель `modules`: `/lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic/`. видите там файл с именем `[Mm]akefile` или `GNUmakefile`? думаю, нет.

возможно, в этом каталоге есть симлинк с именем `build` или `source` (или что-нибудь в этом духе), который указывает на нужный каталог (в котором есть какой-нибудь из перечисленных файлов).

вот и попробуйте указать именно этот путь (`/lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic/build/`) вместо `/lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic/`

Comment: Исправил но снова ошибка

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Comment: Да удалось `Makefile` лежал в папке `/lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic/build` в Makefile исправил строку на `KERNEL_SOURCE := /lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic/build`

Answer (score 2):

Удалите пробелы - используйте вместо них TAB'ы.

Comment: Исправил но снова ошибка

Comment: @timob256, какая? Покажите вывод.

Comment: вбил `make -e` не вывело, как посмотреть ошибку (лог файла также не нашёл).

Comment: @timob256, вижу, Вам уже ответили - извините, только что добрался домой.